# SQL Server Method to Put Top 10 SELECTED rows (all columns) of a joined table into an Array or a variable table

Tags: sql, arrays, sql-server, stored-procedures

I am struggling to figure out how to get this stored procedure to return all appointments for the userId (this is the only input required). Right now it is only returning one appointment. I want it to return all 5 attributes (appointment_id, host_name, visit_start, visit_end, and visit_location) for each appointment associated with the userId, with each appointment separated by {}. So if a visitor has 5 appointments for the day, I want all 5 appointments to be returned (along with the 5 appointment attributes), with each separate appointment enclosed in {}. I also want to take care of the case where a userId has no appointments associated with it. This code works perfectly, but, like I said only returns 1 appointment instead of all that are associated with the userId. I feel like I need an to make an appointment array although I don't believe arrays are part of SQL server. I might need a variable table but i am not sure how to implement one. I am open to any suggestions.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetMeetings]
(

       @userId BIGINT,
       @appointmentId BIGINT OUTPUT,
       @hostName NVARCHAR(101) OUTPUT,
       @startTime DATETIMEOFFSET(7) OUTPUT,
       @endTime DATETIMEOFFSET(7)  OUTPUT,
       @location NVARCHAR(100) OUTPUT

)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON
       SELECT TOP 10
             @appointmentId = appointment_id,
             @hostName = host_name,
             @startTime = visit_start,
             @endtime = visit_end,
             @location = visit_location

       FROM
             dbo.reg_visits v1 INNER JOIN dbo.reg_visitors v2 on v1.reg_visit_id = v2.reg_visits_reg_visit_id
       WHERE
           v2.reg_visits_reg_visit_id IN 
       (SELECT TOP 10
             reg_visits_reg_visit_id AS id 
       FROM
             dbo.reg_visitors
       WHERE visitor_profile_visitor_id = @userId
       ORDER BY
             reg_visitors_id DESC) 
       AND v1.visit_start > GETDATE() ORDER BY v1.reg_visit_id desc
END
```

Comment: This is normally done at the application level, where the database server just returns rows and the client application rolls them up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your select statement should just be

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetMeetings]
(

       @userId BIGINT
)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON
       SELECT TOP 10
             appointment_id,
             host_name,
             visit_start,
             visit_end,
             visit_location
```

We want to return this as a result set and not as an out parameter.  OUTPUT parameters can really only have one value, so that's why you are getting only one appointment back, and it is probably always the last of the 10 rows that you are expecting.  So get rid of all the OUTPUT parameters too and just send in the userid.

Comment: You don’t want to pass in hostName etc anymore, the only parameter you should be passing in client side is userId.

Comment: I updated my answer to include the sproc declaration.  Did you remove all the OUTPUT params?  If you have, and you removed them from the client where you are calling the sproc, can you include the client code in the question?

Comment: i didn't remove them from the client-side ...let me try